# Make speech recognition icon transparent

Tags: android, icons, speech-recognition, transparent

I have a fragment that use the speech recognition of Android. It is work O.K. but I have a text on the fragment which the user need to read. But when I open the speech service the icon cover the text. Is there a way to make the icon of the service transparent  or put it on the side?

Comment: Have you looked for an "alpha" or "opacity" attribute for the icon?

Comment: This is the case.The service is 100% Android device utillity and I don't know which command roll the icon behaiver.This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found this artical.file:///C:/JAVA/Eye_test_Project1/Android%20Speech%20Recognition%20Without%20Dialog%20In%20A%20Custom%20Activity%20-%20Truiton.html
It give exactly waht I want. The voice recognition made in offline and I get several callback which I can use for result and active a bar graph .